# Image Upload & Editing: Implementing in-browser cropping and storing edited images on the server using MERN stack

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mern, multer

I'm working on a project where I want to allow users to upload images, perform in-browser cropping, and store the edited images on the server. I'm using the MERN stack (MongoDB, Express.js, React, Node.js). I've implemented the basic functionality, but I'm struggling with adding in-browser cropping.

```html
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('./db');
const ImageModel = require('./models/ImagesData')
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,'public/Images')
    },
    filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,file.fieldname+"_"+Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage:storage
})

app.post('/upload',upload.single('file'),(req,res)=>{
   ImageModel.create({image:req.file.filename})
   .then(result=>res.json(result))
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
app.get('/getImages',(req,res)=>{
    ImageModel.find()
    .then(Image=>res.json(Image))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
})

app.listen(4000,()=>{
    console.log("Server Running at port 4000")
})
```

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import axios from 'axios';

const Gallery = () => {
  const { user, logout } = useAuth0();
  const [file, setFile] = useState('');
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:4000/getImages')
      .then(res => setImages(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  },[]);

  const handleUpload = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:4000/upload', formData)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        setImages([...images, res.data.image]);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto">
      <div className="flex justify-end">
        <button
          onClick={() => logout({ returnTo: window.location.origin })}
          className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md"
        >
          Logout
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button
          onClick={handleUpload}
          className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md"
        >
          Upload
        </button>
      </div>

      <br />

      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
        {images.map(image => (
          <img
            key={image.id}
            src={`http://localhost:4000/Images/${image.image}`}
            alt="image"
            className="object-fit cover rounded-lg h-48 w-full"
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

The current setup allows users to upload images, but I need assistance in integrating an in-browser cropping tool and ensuring that the cropped image is stored on the server. I'm looking for guidance or examples on how to integrate a cropping tool like react-image-crop into my existing React component and modify the server-side code to handle the cropped image.

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.